# Get data from json and use just one result as value

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use www.football-data.org to get football league standings but i've never used JSON before.

Currently i'm using the following:

```
$uri = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable/';
$reqPrefs['http']['method'] = 'GET';
$reqPrefs['http']['header'] = 'X-Auth-Token:'.$api_key;

$stream_context = stream_context_create($reqPrefs);

$response = file_get_contents($uri, false, $stream_context);
$details = json_decode($response);
```

To try and get the details for one team. At the moment i'm using:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($details);
echo "</pre>";
```

to get the following to show:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_links] => stdClass Object
        (
            [self] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable/?matchday=26
                )

            [soccerseason] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398
                )

        )

    [leagueCaption] => Premier League 2015/16
    [matchday] => 26
    [standing] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_links] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [team] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [href] => http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/338
                                )

                        )

                    [position] => 1
                    [teamName] => Leicester City FC
                    [crestURI] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png
                    [playedGames] => 25
                    [points] => 53
                    [goals] => 47
                    [goalsAgainst] => 27
                    [goalDifference] => 20
                    [wins] => 15
                    [draws] => 8
                    [losses] => 2
                    [home] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [goals] => 21
                            [goalsAgainst] => 13
                            [wins] => 7
                            [draws] => 4
                            [losses] => 1
                        )

                    [away] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [goals] => 26
                            [goalsAgainst] => 14
                            [wins] => 8
                            [draws] => 4
                            [losses] => 1
                        )

                )
```

Firstly, how do I go about getting these values and saving them as a usable variable in PHP?

Secondly, is it possible to just narrow down this data to one team? For example to say:

```
if($details->teamName == 'Manchester United') { $gamesPlayed = $details->gamesPlayed; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an Object which has, amongst others, an array of objects named `standing` and they in turn have `teamName` property. So to get the first one you'll do

```
if($details->standing[0]->teamName == 'Manchester United')
```

Or you can loop over `standing` and get all of them if in case there are multiple entries

Like

```
foreach($details->standing as $record)
{
   if($record->teamName == 'Manchester United')
      $gamesPlayed=$record->playedGames;
}
```

Comment: Well the [0] after standing relates to the order of the league, so for example Leicester are [0] at the moment, but if another team goes above them, they will be [0], so I think it would be safer to loop all of the data and then filter it after? But how would I filter out just the Manchester United stats without knowing their position?

Comment: SO beware this guy is always there to give up-votes to folks that have no special knowledge of anything and also has good words for them too. In fact, make him a mod :)